# reshape2: Passing args to dcast

Tags: r, reshape2

I want to just be able to write a simple wrapper function for dcast (reshape2 package) to be able to read in a file, reshape, and write out to a different file. The wrinkle is that I won't usually know the field names are ahead of time, I just know that I want the first 2 columns, and that there's a 3rd column called 'count'. The function I *want* is something like this.

```
function reshapeAndWrite(path, target)
{
    require(reshape2)

    data = read.csv(path)
    fields = colnames(data)
    data_reshape = dcast(data, fields[1] ~ fields[2], value.var = count)
    write.csv(data_reshape, target)
}
```

However, dcast interprets fields[1] and fields[2] as strings (ie calling dcast(data, "var1" ~ "var2") instead of dcast(data, var1 ~ var2). How can I pass in the column names in a .

I've tried: as.name()/as.symbol() and various combos of eval(), parse(), deparse() and substitute().

The answer to this question could probably be generalized to other packages in the Hadley universe too.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dcast has 'formula' as one of the arguments. So, as an intermediate step you could create a formula-string using your colnames, and put that in the call to dcast:

```
data <- expand.grid(a=LETTERS[1:5],b=c("A","B"))
data$count=1:10

fields <- colnames(data)
casting_formula = sprintf("%s ~ %s", fields[1],fields[2])

dcast(data=data,value.var="count",formula=casting_formula)



  a A  B
1 A 1  6
2 B 2  7
3 C 3  8
4 D 4  9
5 E 5 10
```

Comment: That did it - thanks!